# Dimension of a tensor product following field extension

Tags: vector-spaces, extension-field, tensor-products, tensors

Let E/F be a field extension (assuming finite). Let V be an n-dimensional vector space over F. How to show that the dimension of E ⊗ V over E equals n? I've set up the preliminaries, such as writing a bilinear map from E x V to E ⊗ V and choosing a basis {v_1, ..., v_n}, but don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When you say 1_E do you mean the identity element of E? If E is an extension of F, it is also a vector space over F, so how come we are not choosing another set of basis for the vector space E over F?